# MongoDB saves some dates incorrectly and with different offsets

Tags: mongodb, timezone

My server Timezone is Tehran (GMT+3:30). When I run this command

```
var now = new Date();
now.getTimezoneOffset();
```

I get -210 which is correct.
but when I save 2 dates in database, MongoDb saves them with different offsets!

2023-10-13 -> 2023-10-12T20:30:00.000+00:00 (+3:30)

1966-07-23 -> 1966-07-22T19:30:00.000+00:00 (+4:30)

the second date is invalid and should be 1966-07-22T20:30:00.000+00:00

I have another MongoDB instance on my local computer that saves the date correctly.
What's the problem with the server instance?

my c# program:

```
var year = 1;

var month = 1;

var day = 1;

Console.Write("Year:");

year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Month:");

month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Day:");

day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var date = new DateTime(year, month, day, 0,0, 0);


const string connectionUri = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

var client = new MongoClient(connectionUri);

var collection = client.GetDatabase("TestDb").GetCollection<DateClass>("DateClass");

  var obj = new DateClass();

  obj.DateAndTime = date;

  await collection.InsertOneAsync(obj);

  public class DateClass
  {
      public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: I think your local PC might have a different timezone and your server might have a different timezone on which your app is currently running. It would be helpful if you can give more context around the problem that you are facing.

Comment: their timezones are identical (iran) and both instance return -210 when I run getTimezoneOffset() . the problem is the server instance saves dates with different offsets. some dates with+3:30 (-210) and others with +4:30 (-270) offset. the application is very simple and only writes a date in db.

Comment: Are you running your application inside a docker container?

Comment: no, I'm not using a docker container. It's a simple c# console program running on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter.

Comment: Ok, then I think maybe you should check whether the timezone of your server which is Tehran(+3.30) matches with the timezone set in your MongoDB configuration.

Comment: I've added the c# code to the question

Comment: If MongoDB timezone doesn't match, why MongoDB saves most dates correctly and running getTimezoneOffset() returns -210 which is correct? By the way, Where can I find MongoDB configuration file? and where's the timezone setting in that file? Thanks.

Comment: MongoDB inherits the same timezone as your server's. But in your case, maybe you can try restarting the MongoDB service on your server. Maybe that can help.

Comment: This may be related to the Iran timezone issue last year being resolved and staying permanently in standard time. See Microsoft statement [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/daylight-saving-time-time-zone/iran-2023-time-zone-update-now-available/ba-p/3805707#:~:text=After%20returning%20to%20the%20standard,30%20time%20zone%20going%20forward.). Does the difference exist when you do both dates in Oct 2023 instead on one in July 1966 when the timezone would have been +4:30? If not then that is expected behaviour.

Comment: my local pc has the same timezone (tehran +3:30) but it saves the 1966-07-23 correctly as 1966-07-22T20:30:00.000+00:00. server instance saves 2023-07-01 as 2023-06-30T19:30:00.000+00:00 and 2023-10-01 as 2023-09-30T20:30:00.000+00:00. it's definitly related to the iran timezone issue, but I can't find how to resolve it on the server. I want to know why two instances of mongodb with same timezone are working differently. one of them always uses +3:30 and one of them uses +4:30 for some dates and +3:30 for others. where can I config this behavior?

Comment: That is probably more of a server issue than MongoDB issue. You would need to make sure your server OS is patched to accommodate the timezone resolution issue. This has been discussed over at unix.stackechange see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693875/how-to-disable-dst-changes-for-a-timezone). Might be a good question to ask over there.

Answer (score 0):

When you save a date in MongoDB, it gets stored in the BSON format, which includes a **UTC timestamp**.
However, MongoDB does not store time zone information with the date by default.

To resolve this inconsistency, you should examine your application code for both the date insertion and retrieval processes to ensure that all dates are correctly converted to UTC before storing them in MongoDB.

Here is an example in Javascript:

```js
// Assume dateStr is in Tehran time zone
var dateStr = "2023-10-13T00:00:00+03:30";
var date = new Date(dateStr);

// Convert the date to UTC
date = new Date(date.toUTCString());

// Store the UTC date in MongoDB
// ...

// When retrieving the date from MongoDB
// Convert it back to the Tehran time zone if needed
```